# Moving MANY partitions from one table to another -Mysql

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I have a table with many partitions by date

**I want to move some of the oldest partitions to another table.**

I succeed moving the oldest partition by following the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-management-exchange.html)
but when I try to move more partitions I get: Error Code: 1737. Found a row that does not match the partition

So, I deleted the oldest partition and move the next partition -but then the rows from the first partitions returned to the original table (I did NOT see any documentation for record that go back...)

How can I move the three first partitions to another table?
THANKS

```
CREATE TABLE `TestPartA` (
    `Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `Time` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `Slot` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    `Text` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Name`, `Text`, `Time`),
    INDEX `ClusterTimeIdx` (`Name`, `Time`, `Slot`),
    INDEX `Time` (`Time`)
)
 PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(TIME))
(PARTITION p20190407 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2019-04-07')) ,
 PARTITION p20190421 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2019-04-21')) ,
 PARTITION p20190428 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2019-04-28')),
 PARTITION p20190505 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2019-05-05')))  ;

CREATE TABLE TestPartB LIKE TestPartA;
ALTER TABLE TestPartB REMOVE PARTITIONING;

insert into TestPartA values ('A','2019-04-02',1,'W1');
insert into TestPartA values ('A','2019-04-04',1,'W1');
insert into TestPartA values ('A','2019-04-08',1,'W1');
insert into TestPartA values ('A','2019-04-20',1,'W1');
insert into TestPartA values ('A','2019-05-01',1,'W1');

SELECT PARTITION_NAME, TABLE_ROWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TestPartA';
```

[image]

```
-- move the first partition 
ALTER TABLE TestPartA EXCHANGE PARTITION p20190407 WITH TABLE TestPartB; -- Works GREAT
select * from TestPartA;
select * from TestPartB;
SELECT PARTITION_NAME, TABLE_ROWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TestPartA'; -- this is not working any more - but according to documentation it happens sometimes
```

[image]

```
--move the second partition
ALTER TABLE TestPartA EXCHANGE PARTITION p20190421 WITH TABLE TestPartB; -- FAILED

ALTER TABLE TestPartA drop PARTITION p20190407;

ALTER TABLE TestPartA EXCHANGE PARTITION p20190421 WITH TABLE TestPartB; -- Succeed but the rows from the first partitions returned to table A
select * from TestPartA;
select * from TestPartB;
```

[image]

Comment: Why are there partitions here? Is it to simplify the process of deleting old data?

Comment: yes @Strawberry.
It is a really big table...